# Do moves in rust always copy the stack allocation?

Tags: rust, move-semantics, memcpy, stack-allocation

Lets say I have a large, non-`Copy`, stack allocated data structure, and then I move it a bunch of times:

```rust
struct Foo(u8);

fn main() {
    // A big (8MiB) stack allocation
    let big_stack_data: [Foo; 0x800000] = gen_data();

    let a = big_stack_data; // moves into a
    let b = a; // moves into b
    let c = b; // moves into c
    let d = c; // moves into d
    let e = d; // moves into e
    let f = e; // moves into f
    let g = f; // moves into g
    let h = g; // moves into h
    let i = h; // moves into i
}
```

Will this actually copy the 8MiB of data each time the array value is moved? Will the compiler actually try to allocate 80 MiB for `main`'s stack?

It seems to me that it doesn't have to. It seems to me that since each move invalidates the source variable, all this memory allocation and copying cost is not necessary and the compiler could simply use the same allocation for each new variable and not actually copy anything. Is this not correct?

Comment: The LLVM optimizer will almost certainly elide all of the moves in this example.

Comment: Semantically move is always a memcopy, however compiler is allowed to optimize away any moves it sees unnecessary.

Comment: Just see for yourself: https://godbolt.org/z/ffxEhce87

Comment: While the compiler is _allowed_ to optimize the moves out, you don't get a guarantee that it will. You don't want data structures with a size of 8 MB to live on the stack anyway, so I'd recommend you just don't do that.

Comment: Your statements are correct. The key word is "could". Optimizations are always on a best-effort basis and if you require that guarantee (that no copies occur) then you must enforce it yourself, for example by passing around a mutable reference to the array instead of passing it by value.